# Question put 'on hold' was edited, but it was not reopened. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, reopen-closed

Why is the question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268914/summation-notation still on hold in Cross Validated, after I had edited it by re-wording and providing more details?

Comment: People should look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268914/summation-notation (note that not giving a URL obligates anyone interested to search for themselves). In general, editing is necessary but not sufficient. There have to be sufficient votes to re-open. Otherwise put, whether a question seems clear and on-topic to you is not decisive: it has to seem clear and on-topic to others.  Flagging in this way will let other people decide whether to vote to re-open.

Comment: There also has to be time for people to read it: your last edit, finally defining the variables $Y$ & $y$, was made only 10 minutes before you posted this question in Meta. Still unclear are the role of $u$, which makes an entrance early on, only to play no further part in the proceedings; & in which book or paper Hansen et al published something that bears on the matter.